# AWS Glue crawler not showing up in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am new to AWS Athena and I'm having trouble with it. Basically, I have a dynamodb table that I'd like to be queryable. I created an AWS Glue crawler for this purpose. It seems that it *should* show up in Athena automatically, but it isn't. Do I have to create a Glue Job to manually dump the data into an S3 bucket and then configure Athena to use that bucket? I feel like there should be a way for me to skip all of that and just configure Athena to listen/check the crawler?

Thanks
Hassan

Comment: Can you see the table in gluw catalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to crawl data in Dyanamo db using Glue Crawler. Then create an Glue job to store the data in S3 bucket to query with Athena. Check this link for more details:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simplify-amazon-dynamodb-data-extraction-and-analysis-by-using-aws-glue-and-amazon-athena/

Comment: Also, when using the crawler, make sure that the IAM role you are using is targeting to the S3 folder where your data is.